# jQuery CRUD operations on MySQL table

Tags: javascript, jquery

**FIXED BUT HAVE TO WAIT ONE DAY**
I got a table from MySQL on my php page. First I needed to sort the columns which is working great. Now I need to be able to edit, add und delete the rows which I can't seem to get to work

I already tried every pre-built plugin I was able to find but nothing worked. I always wasn't able to save the edits into my database. If that comes to your mind: Yes I set up the connection correctly.
I'm to unexperienced to write that code by myself that's why I'm asking you for help

What the "plugin" should do is that I can edit, add and delete rows. It should be saved into my database the second I hit save.
I appreciate any help. Even some starting/important parts for the code that I have to finish myself

Comment: Can you please post the code you tried, and maybe the name of the plugin you used ?

Comment: the one I reached the most with is [that one](https://www.webslesson.info/2017/05/live-table-data-edit-delete-using-tabledit-plugin-in-php.html). Yes, I adjusted the database settings and my table id

Comment: Do you have any error in your console ? Any request failing in the network tab ?

Comment: No errors. Network says it calls action.php (also on webslesson page) which I adjusted correctly (mysqli escape; my table; my names). Then the field has changed. But after reload it's like nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it while reading everything again.
OLD:

```
if($input["action"] === 'edit') {
 $query = "UPDATE Test SET 
 Date = '$date', 
 User = '$user',
 // some more stuff but enough
 WHERE Num = '$num'";

 $connect->query($query);
}
```

NEW:

```
if($input["action"] === 'edit') {
 $query = "UPDATE Test SET 
 Date = '$date', 
 User = '$user'
 //some more stuff but enough
 WHERE Num = '$num'";

 $connect->query($query);
}
```

Had do delete one , after the last column to change.